# <Router basename="/SnapScout"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I encountered the error on React:
 is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the  won't render anything.

my App.js file is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PhotoContextProvider from "./context/PhotoContext";
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate, } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Item from "./components/Item";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";

class App extends Component {
  // Prevent page reload, clear input, set URL and push history on submit
  handleSubmit = (e, history, searchInput) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.reset();
    let url = `/search/${searchInput}`;
    history.push(url);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <PhotoContextProvider>
        <HashRouter basename="/SnapScout">
          <div className="container">
            <Route
              render={(props) => (
                <Header
                  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  history={props.history}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Routes>
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => <Navigate to="/mountain" />}
              />

              <Route
                path="/mountain"
                render={() => <Item searchTerm="mountain" />}
              />
              <Route path="/beach" render={() => <Item searchTerm="beach" />} />
              <Route path="/bird" render={() => <Item searchTerm="bird" />} />
              <Route path="/food" render={() => <Item searchTerm="food" />} />
              <Route
                path="/search/:searchInput"
                render={(props) => (
                  <Search searchTerm={props.match.params.searchInput} />
                )}
              />
              <Route element={NotFound} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </HashRouter>
      </PhotoContextProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to alter   to no effect, still getting a plane white screen with the  error:  is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the  won't render anything.

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you trying to use? `Routes` and `Navigate` are `react-router-dom@6` exports, but you are rendering `Route` components using the `react-router-dom@5` syntax/API. You've some `Route` components outside the `Routes` component. Check the browser console as I'm sure you've also some errors. Check the installed version by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal in the projects root directory and report back what is installed. Are you in the middle of upgrading from one version to the other?

Comment: I'm running on react-router-dom@6.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code snippet you are mixing `react-router-dom@5` and `react-router-dom@6` exports and `Route` component API/syntax.

In `react-router-dom@6`:

1. There are no longer any route props (*e.g. `match`, `history`, and `location`*). Any components needing to access the "old route props" will need to use the new React hooks, i.e.

   - `useParams` for `match.params`
   - `useLocation` for `location`
   - `useNavigate` for `navigate` function (*instead of `history` object*)
2. The `Route` component doesn't take any `component`, or `children`
   or `render` function props, it instead takes a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

A refactor of your `App` component may look something like the following:

```
import {
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // Prevent page reload, clear input, set URL and push history on submit
  const handleSubmit = (e, searchInput) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.reset();
    const url = `/search/${searchInput}`;
    navigate(url);
  };

  return (
    <PhotoContextProvider>
      <div className="container">
        <Header handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/mountain" />} />
          <Route path="/mountain" element={<Item searchTerm="mountain" />} />
          <Route path="/beach" element={<Item searchTerm="beach" />} />
          <Route path="/bird" element={<Item searchTerm="bird" />} />
          <Route path="/food" element={<Item searchTerm="food" />} />
          <Route path="/search/:searchInput" element={<Search />} />
          <Route element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </PhotoContextProvider>
  );
};
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router basename="/SnapScout">
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Note that the `HashRouter` was moved ***up*** the ReactTree to allow the `App` component to use and access the routing context so the `useNavigate` hook could be used.

Run the app and navigate to `"/#/SnapScout"`

[image: Edit router-basename-snapscout-is-not-able-to-match-the-url-because-it-does]

[image]